# pthread sleep() function stop whole execution

Tags: c++, pthreads, sleep

I am writing a multi threads c++ program, follows a simple function I used for tests. If I comment out the sleep() there, the program will work. However if I put the sleep() in the loop, there will be no output on screen, it seems like the sleep() kills the whole execution. Please help. Will the sleep function kill execution of a pthread program? How can I sleep the threads?

```
void *shop(void *array){
int second = difftime( time(0), start );

// init shopping list with characters
string *info = (string *)array;
int size = stoi(info[0]);
string character = info[1];
string career = info[2];

if ( career == "Auror" ) {
    int process = 3;
    while (process < size+1) {
        int shop = stoi(info[process]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&counter);
        cout << process << endl;
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter);
        process++;
    }
}
```

The output without sleep is:

```
3
4
5
6
3
4
5
6
```

The output with sleep() is like:

```
3
3
```

It breaks the while loop.

Comment: I was using two threads when testing

Comment: how you define and initialize mutex object? what is returned by pthread_mutex_lock ?

Comment: I defined like this: pthread_mutex_t counter = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; My friend told me it may caused by I put the sleep in a lock. However, I tried to moved it out, and it still not working, its just breaks the whold execution

Comment: okay, and again "what is returned by pthread_mutex_lock ?" it looks like the mutex is not get locked, so pthread_mutex_lock should return error code.

Comment: I think I found the problem, actually the sleep() in the thread not ending the whole execution, its just the main finished. I add a sleep(100) in the main function just let the program keep going on(i have a sub function create threads), otherwise if the main ends, all the threads wont last anymore... is that the reason???

Comment: not possible, `main` will not finish, until your thread finishes. Ones thread have finished, then main will finish.

Comment: Is this the only thread you have ?

Comment: from where you call `shop()` function ? from `main` or thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the main thread wait for the child thread to finish up its task through pthread_join.
The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread must be joinable.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, if the main thread dies, your app dies including all "Worker Threads".

Add a `getchar()` or a `system("pause")` or whatever in your main thread.